# drop parent directory from path when uploading artifacts from jenkins to artifactory

Tags: regex, jenkins, artifactory

I need to upload the following files from within a jenkins jobs workspace to artifactory..

```
./PreCompiledWeb/SomeWebsite/*.*
```

..but I want to drop PreCompiledWeb from the path, so that the final artifactory path is more like

```
repository/project/component/version/SomeWebsite
```

and not

```
repository/project/component/version/PreCompiledWeb/SomeWebSite
```

is there a way to do this with a regex or a tweek in the jenkins job to switch the current working directory? (I'm using regex as I need to also exclude specific files from the upload)

I've simplified what I'm trying to do for demonstration and fashioned a regex that works in regex101, matching everything AFTER PreCompiledWeb, however the artifactory plugin doesn't find any artifacts when I do this...

```
(?<=PrecompiledWeb/)SomeWebsite/.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/CjDYxa/1

The plugin/artifactory seems to need a path relative to the current working directory so only works when PreCompiledWeb is included rather than just asserting there is a match based on the regex.

Comment: How are you removing it from the path? What are you using this regex with?

Comment: the regex is in an artifactory filespec file, referenced from the artifactory plugin in jenkins. the slave it's running on is Windows 2012 Server, artifactory is on the master jenkins server on Centos.

Comment: The full regex is (?i)(?!.*(Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll|vwd.web.config|Web.Config|website.publishproj|wse3policyCache.config))(?<=PrecompiledWeb\/)SomeWebsite/.*  which uses a case insensitive search, negative look ahead to remove specific files and positive look behind to match SomeWebsite providing it's within the PrecompiledWeb folder. looks fine in regex101 and there are artifacts whose filepath will match with this regex however the artifactory plugin finds no artifacts